# Jcrop coordinates in Safari and Chrome overwritten

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, safari, webkit, jcrop

I am using the [Jcrop](http://deepliquid.com/content/Jcrop.html) plugin for jQuery for photo manipulation. I finally have it working successfully in Firefox and IE8, but am experiencing some weird behavior in Chrome and Safari.

**Jcrop code**

```
var api;
$(window.load(function() {
    var orimg = $('#image1');
    //Create Image to get dimensions of full size photo
    var pic = $('<img>').attr('src', orimg.attr('src')).css('display', 'none').appendTo('#form1');
    var h = pic.height();
    var w = pic.width();

    //set defaults for jcrop
    var opt = {
        aspectRatio: 1,
        onSelect: storeCoords, 
        onChange: storeCoords, 
        trueSize: [w, h], //actual size of pic vs. styled size on page
        bgColor: '#EEEEEE',
        bgOpacity: .7,
        setSelect: [150, 150, 50, 50]
    };

    $('#crop_button').click(function() {
        //initialize jcrop
        api = $.Jcrop(orimg, opt);
    });

    $('#cancel_button').click(function() {
        api.destroy();
    });

});

function storeCoords(c) {
    $('#X').val(c.x);
    $('#Y').val(c.y);
    $('#W').val(c.w);
    $('#H').val(c.h);
}
```

Originally I just thought that it wasn't storing the coordinates when the `storeCoords` function was being called. However I added the following code to the `storeCoords` function to see what was happening:

```
var msg = '';
$.each(c, function(index, value) {
    msg += index + ':' + value + ' ';
});
$('#debug_output').html(msg + '<br />');
```

In Firefox and IE it would output the coordinates each resize/move of the crop box. In Chrome/Safari (when using the `onChange:` property) I get one line of correct data but then it proceeds to overwrite that data with zeros.

- x:50 y:50 x2:150 y2:150 w:100 h:100
- x:50 y:50 x2:150 y2:150 w:100 h:100
- x:0 y:0 x2:0 y2:0 w:0 h:0  x:0 y:0
- x2:0 y2:0 w:0 h:0  x:0 y:0 x2:0 y2:0
- w:0 h:0  x:0 y:0 x2:0 y2:0 w:0 h:0
- x:0 y:0 x2:0 y2:0 w:0 h:0

using the `onSelect:` property by itself produces all zeros (Chrome/Safari)

So I'm at a loss as to why they are calling/overwriting the values.

**EDIT**

I've updated the code to use `$(function(){})` instead of `$(window).load(function(){})` and am experiencing the same results. I have put up a [demo page](http://jon3laze.com/projects/jcrop/test.html) that produces the same results. I'm not sure if this is a bug with Jcrop or something I'm doing. It only happens when I specify the `trueSize` property. The non-minified version of the plugin can be viewed [here](http://jon3laze.com/projects/jcrop/assets/js/jquery.Jcrop.js).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am going to chalk this up to being a bug in the plugin. I've submitted a [bug report](http://code.google.com/p/jcrop/issues/detail?id=46) to the project on Google code. I have resorted to resizing the image via the back-end code rather than styling for the interim. Thanks for the suggestions, I will update this if I hear back on the bug.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have a double-bound event that's causing the odd behavior in some browsers.  Instead of `$(window.load(function () { ... }))` try just `$(function () { ... })`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to reposition your object as you use the function onChange and onSelect as follow:

```
    imgObj.Jcrop(
          {
        onChange: function (coords) { YOUR PARAMS HERE; ScrollTo(scrollObj); },
        onSelect: function (coords) { YOUR PARAMS HERE; ScrollTo(scrollObj); },
        addClass: 'jcrop-centered'
          });

function ScrollTo(scrollObj)
        {
          var scrollto = scrollObj.height() * 2/5,
              scrolle  = scrollObj.width() * 2/5;
          scrollObj.scrollTop(scrollto);
          scrollObj.scrollLeft(scrolle);
        };
```

Try this it works for me :-)